# Get user input value info when i render the html doc using iframe in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, iframe

I have an input tag in html doc that I get from API.

```
<input placeholder="Enter Name" type="text"/>
```

And I am rendering this in react in .js component with iframe srcDoc,
When user enters anything on the input field then i want to capture that info in react component but i am not sure how i can capture input value that is part of html doc which i am rendering using iframe.

Can someone please help with this or any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

I have used one p tag for showing input value. You can customise according to your requirement. Please try below updated code :-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const FULL_NAME = '';

  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    if (event.origin !== window.location.origin) return; // Check origin for security

    const { type, payload } = event.data;
    if (type === 'inputValue') {
      setInputValue(payload);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

  // Dynamically construct the srcDoc based on the condition
  const iframeSrcDoc = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>IFrame Content</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        ${FULL_NAME && `<span>name: ${FULL_NAME}</span>`}
        <input placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" onInput="parent.postMessage({type: 'inputValue', payload: this.value}, '*');" />
      </body>
    </html>
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Input value from iframe: {inputValue}</p>
      <iframe title="iframe" srcDoc={iframeSrcDoc} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: This worked, Thank you.
I have one more question, can you please help. 
Is there a way to conditionally render HTMl doc ?

Comment: You want iframe srcDoc to change conditionally ? or you want to render different html in in your component conditionally in the return statement ?

Comment: From BE html i am getting `Name: NAME`, so i want to show this field if i have the value on UI, Something like this does not work `NAME && Name: NAME`, So if there is a way to make changes in html and pass props from react or iframe so this field renders only if it is available ?

Comment: `const test = { Name: NAME }` this must be an object right ? so you can fetch like `test.Name` and you can show like `{name && <p>Name: {test.Name}</p>}` inside render function.

Comment: Hmm, got it. Updated code above. Let me know if this is correct or not ?

Comment: As you mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78133280/conditionally-render-a-field-from-html-into-react-using-iframe
I am considering FULL_NAME will be coming from BE but right now I have passed  static empty string here but if you pass any value in the variable then you will see span tag showing on srcDoc of iframe.